# Company Maven POM nested structure

Tags: java, maven

Well I'm working on a company POM Maven structure. I want a structure like the example below. Now I have two questions!

- Is this possible for a project to call the parent pom? (considering
  that they are all installed in the local Maven repository).
- If I adda License block to the Company POM, do I have to add to the
  project POM a new License block?

All feedback, suggestions etc are welcome. Thank you in advance!

## Company

**Company POM**

Contains organization information, not to much.

```
<groupId>org.company</groupId>
<artifactId>company</artifactId>
<version>1</version>

<modules>
    <module>company-parent</module>
</modules>
```

**Company Parent POM**

Defines for all the projects basic dependencies/plugins (management).

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>company</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>company-parent</artifactId>
```

## Project

**Project POM**

Project based organization information (developers etc).

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>company-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</parent>

<groupId>org.company.project</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<modules>
    <module>project-parent</module>
</modules>
```

**Project Parent POM**

Defines for the current project used dependencies/plugins (management).

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.company.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>

<modules>
    <module>company-module-1</module>
    <module>company-module-2</module>
    <module>company-module-3</module>
</modules>
```

**Project Module POM's**

The modules with each his own buid, dependencies and stuff.

**Module 1**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.company.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>project-module-1</artifactId>
```

**Module 2**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.company.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>project-module-2</artifactId>
```

**Module 3**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.company.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>project-module-3</artifactId>
```

Answer (score 1):

A Maven child project does not *"call"* a parent project. The POM is declarative, not imperative. Similar to Java class inheritance the child gets the parent's settings and can override them or add new ones. See [Maven, POM Reference, 2.2.2. Inheritance](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance).

So, no, you don't have to declare the parent project's licence settings in the child project once again if they are supposed to be the same there.